# TIdHTTP and TRESTClient with SSl on Android

Tags: android, delphi, openssl

[It is possible to](https://web.archive.org/web/20130921062017/http://www.monien.net/delphi-xe5-ssl-https-on-different-platforms-with-tidhttp-and-trestclient/) use TRESTClient with HTTPS/SSL on iOS and Mac OSX in Delphi by setting OpenSSL library path. But is there a way to make it work on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy's OpenSSL support works the same way on Android as it does on all other non-iOS platforms.  On every platform other than iOS, Indy loads OpenSSL dynamically at runtime.  You can use Indy's `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to tell Indy where the OpenSSL DLLs/Dylibs are located, if not in the app's folder.  On iOS, OpenSSL is statically compiled into the app at compile-time instead of dynamically loaded at runtime, so there is no `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` function to call.

Comment: Thanks, Remy! Also could you please tell me where OpenSSL libs are located on Android?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer, and I can't find that info online anywhere. You might have to look on an actual Android device or simulator.